# Grails Database Reverse Engineer Plugin Errors

Tags: grails, plugins

Environment

```
Grails 2.4.4
PostgreSQL 9.4
JDK 1.7
```

This was my [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34906579/grails-database-reverse-engineer-plugin-not-found).

So, I changed `/myApp/target/work/plugins/db-reverse-engineer-4.0.0/scripts/DbReverseEngineer.groovy` like this.

```
mergedConfig.driverClassName = dsConfig.driverClassName ?: 'org.postgresql.Driver'
mergedConfig.password = dsConfig.password ?: ''
mergedConfig.username = dsConfig.username ?: 'postgres'
mergedConfig.url = dsConfig.url ?: "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myDB"
```

And I changed plugin and dependency per Burt's and Emmanuel's advice. And when I run `grails db-reverse-engineer command` I get this error.

```
Compilation error: startup failed:
Compile error during compilation with javac.
/home/Documents/Grails_Workspace/myApp/target/work/plugins/cache-1.1.8/src/java/grails/plugin/cache/web/GenericResponseWrapper.java:203: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
/home/Documents/Grails_Workspace/myApp/target/work/plugins/cache-1.1.8/src/java/grails/plugin/cache/web/filter/PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:389: error: cannot find symbol
            contentType = response.getContentType();
                                  ^
  symbol:   method getContentType()
  location: variable response of type HttpServletResponse
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

Can anyone please explain to me what these errors mean and how to fix them?
I tried to use `Grails 3.0.12` and follow `DB reverse engineer` tutorial from Grails 3 but I got lost more than ever.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

```
/Grails_Workspace/dbTest/target/work/plugins/db-reverse-engineer-4.0.0/src/groovy/grails/plugin/reveng/Reenigne.groovy: 92: Access to org.hibernate.cfg.Environment#DRIVER is forbidden @ line 92, column 14.
        properties[Environment.DRIVER] = driverClass
.               ^
.    
Access to org.hibernate.cfg.Environment#PASS is forbidden @ line 93, column 14.
        properties[Environment.PASS] = password
.               ^
.    
Access to org.hibernate.cfg.Environment#URL is forbidden @ line 94, column 14.
        properties[Environment.URL] = url
.               ^
.    
Access to org.hibernate.cfg.Environment#USER is forbidden @ line 95, column 14.
        properties[Environment.USER] = username
.               ^
.    
Access to org.hibernate.cfg.Environment#DIALECT is forbidden @ line 97, column 15.
            properties[Environment.DIALECT] = dialect
.                ^
.    
Access to org.hibernate.cfg.Environment#DEFAULT_SCHEMA is forbidden @ line 100, column 15.
            properties[Environment.DEFAULT_SCHEMA] = defaultSchema
.                ^
.    
Access to org.hibernate.cfg.Environment#DEFAULT_CATALOG is forbidden @ line 103, column 15.
            properties[Environment.DEFAULT_CATALOG] = defaultCatalog
                 ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is from the [cache](http://grails.org/plugin/cache) plugin, not the reverse-engineer plugin. If you're not using it, delete it from `BuildConfig.groovy`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I deleted it and I'm getting different errors. It has to do with `Reengine.groovy` Could you please take a look at my edit?  Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Try deleting the target directory, then running `grails compile` and then see if it works after that

Comment: Thank you. I've deleted the target directory and ran `grails compile` but I'm still having the same error. Is it a hibernate thing? Where can I even start to research?

Answer (score -1):

That error is from the cache plugin delete it from BuildConfig.groovy and add following in dependencies

```
compile "net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:2.4.6"
```